# cURL request to Unix socket from php

Tags: php, sockets, unix, curl

How can I execute following curl call from php

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/images/json
```

I went through  [this list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) of options available for `curl_setopt` but couldn't find any option related to above `--unix-socket`

I got above curl call from [this](https://superuser.com/a/925610/388121) answer.

**Edit:**
From [this](http://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/01/08/curl-7-40-0-unix-domain-sockets-and-smb/) blog, can we somehow use `CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH` option in php ?

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party here, but just for completeness...

This has been added in PHP version 7.0.7 with cURL 7.40.0. See the [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) function page in the PHP manual and search for `CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this would work, but have you tried fsockopen?

Something like this **might** work, I haven't tried it.

[fsockopen on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)

```
$fs = fsockopen('/var/run/docker.sock');

fwrite($fs, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: http:/images/json\r\n\r\n");

    while (!feof($fs)) {
        print fread($fs,256);
    }
```

[feof on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php)

Comment: are there any libraries / wrappers for this. 
 https://github.com/php-http/socket-client this library supports unix socket domain